# Pseudo elements not aligning with anchor tag border

Tags: html, css, flexbox, box-sizing

I have the following CSS3 button animation:

HTML::

```
<a href="" class="btn">
  <span>
        Hover on Me
  </span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
/* line 1, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* line 8, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* line 82, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* line 85, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* line 93, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: transparent;
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0.65em 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* line 19, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ff0000;
  transition: all 0.85s;
}


/* line 29, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-105%, 0, 0);
}


/* line 33, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate3d(105%, 0, 0);
}


/* line 41, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn > span:before,
.btn > span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2px;
  background: #ff0000;
  transition: all 0.85s;
}


/* line 51, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn > span:before {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 105%, 0);
}


/* line 55, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn > span:after {
  right: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -105%, 0);
}


/* line 65, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after,
.btn:active:before,
.btn:active:after,
.btn:focus:before,
.btn:focus:after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


/* line 71, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:hover > span:before,
.btn:hover > span:after,
.btn:active > span:before,
.btn:active > span:after,
.btn:focus > span:before,
.btn:focus > span:after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now the problem is that the borders i have created using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements , don't exactly align on top of the border for of the anchor tag, it looks like its 2px inside the button.

I have added the `box-sizing:border-box` property, but i still get the same result , Why am i not able to align the pseudo elements on top of the anchor border ?

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gaueaa1p/)**

As you can see i have used the following property, but still don't get the desired result:

```
*,*:before,*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pseudo elements are children of the element they are applied to, in this case the anchor `btn`, their border won't align on top of the `btn` but immediate inside it.

Adding [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) doesn't change that. Its purpose is to tell the element that its set border/padding size should be included in its set width.

So either you have to move the pseudo's by giving them a negative position, or, in this case, and the absolute simplest, move some of the properties to the `span`.

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0.65em 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
/* line 1, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* line 8, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* line 82, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* line 85, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* line 93, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0.65em 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* line 19, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ff0000;
  transition: all 0.85s;
}


/* line 29, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-105%, 0, 0);
}


/* line 33, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate3d(105%, 0, 0);
}


/* line 41, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn > span:before,
.btn > span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2px;
  background: #ff0000;
  transition: all 0.85s;
}


/* line 51, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn > span:before {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 105%, 0);
}


/* line 55, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn > span:after {
  right: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -105%, 0);
}


/* line 65, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:hover:before,
.btn:hover:after,
.btn:active:before,
.btn:active:after,
.btn:focus:before,
.btn:focus:after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


/* line 71, C:/xampp/htdocs/fs/borderAnimation/scss/style.scss */

.btn:hover > span:before,
.btn:hover > span:after,
.btn:active > span:before,
.btn:active > span:after,
.btn:focus > span:before,
.btn:focus > span:after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=../css/style.map */
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn">
  <span>
      Hover on Me
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: just one more question , in that case why do the psudo elements applied to the `<a>` itself show inside the <a> ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Because that's how pseudo elements work. They renders similar as the `span` you have, being child elements to `a`. That's why the above works, as the pseudo and the `span` are siblings. Does that make sense? ... I mean, instead of the pseudo you could add 2 more `span`, one _before_ and one _after_ the existing `span`, and achieve the same result.

Comment: actually i am still having a scrabled brain about this because when the padding, border etc are on the <a> tag , even the psudo elements applied on the <a> show inside the <a> and don't exactly touch the top and bottom of the <a> , but when the padding , border etc is applied to the span , the psudo elements suddenly align with the border of the span :|

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Ahh ... now I understand what you ask. Why the pseudo on the `span` work is that they are absolute positioned relative to the anchor `a`, not the `span` itself, hence they will overlap the `span`'s border. Does this make sense now?

Comment: thank u and just to make your point amply apparent , adding a `border:2px solid orange` to the <a> makes this obvious ! ...... Thank you sir  .